# Regex which matches URN by rfc8141

Tags: c#, .net, regex, urn

I am struggling to find a Regex which could match a URN as described in [rfc8141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141).
I have tried this one:

`\A(?i:urn:(?!urn:)(?<nid>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,31}):(?<nss>(?:[a-z0-9()+,-.:=@;$_!*']|%[0-9a-f]{2})+))\z`

but this one only matches the first part of the URN without the components.

For example lets say we have the corresponding URN: `urn:example:a123,0%7C00~&z456/789?+abc?=xyz#12/3` We should match the following groups:

- NID - example
- NSS - a123,0%7C00~&z456/789 (from the last ':' tll we match '?+' or '?=' or '#'
- r-component - abc (from '?+' till '?=' or '#'')
- f-component - 12/3 (from '#' till end)

Comment: could you provide an example please with expected result ?

Comment: Yep, lets say we have the corresponding URN:

Comment: Yep, lets say we have the corresponding URN:
```urn:example:a123,0%7C00~&z456/789?+abc?=xyz#12/3```

We should match the following groups:
* NID - example
* NSS - ```a123,0%7C00~&z456/789``` (from the last ':' tll we match '?+' or '?=' or '#'
* r-component - ```abc``` (from '?+' till '?=' or '#'')
* f-component - ```12/3``` (from '#' till end)

Comment: Make sure you read section 3.2 (examples) in the rfc8141.

Comment: this section refers to the equivalence rules between the URNs. How do you think this is related to the question I asked? Please be more specific if you have something in mind @jdweng

Comment: Isn't that what matching is all about?  A good test would be to try all the examples with the solution.

Comment: @jdweng matching is not equivalency. The author wants to parse the URN so that he could have access to the different semantic parts of the urn. This could be achieved by using regex grouping.

Comment: For code to work properly, ALL the examples in rfc8141 must pass.  The examples show matching examples and non-matching examples.

Comment: The is not a simple parse exercise.  The op want to MATCH.  There are different variations of the structure and Upper/Lower case can be ignored on the prefix, but cannot be ignored on the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't read all the specifications, so there may be other rules to implement, but it should put you on the way for the optional components:

```
\A(?i:urn:(?!urn:)(?<nid>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,31}):(?<nss>(?:[-a-z0-9()+,.:=@;$_!*'&~\/]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)(?:\?\+(?<rcomponent>.*?))?(?:\?=(?<qcomponent>.*?))?(?:#(?<fcomponent>.*?))?)\z
```

explanations:

- `(?<nss>(?:[-a-z0-9()+,.:=@;$_!*'&~\/]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)` : The `-` has been moved to the beginning of the list to be considered in the allowed chars, or else it means "range from `,` to `.`". The characters `&`, `~` and `/` (has to be escaped with "\") have also been added to the list, or else it won't match your example.
- optional components: `(?:\?\+(?<rcomponent>.*?))?` : inside an optional non-capturing group `(?:)?` to prevent capturing the identifier (the `?+`, `?=` and `#` part). The chars `?` and `+` have to be escaped with "\". Will capture anything (`.`) but in lazy mode (`*?`) or else the first component found would capture everything until the end of the string.

See working example in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SxOh4R/1)

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you so much! It works perfectly. This is exactly what I needed! The only thing which I have added for now is - to not match when the `nid` group ends with `-` which is specified in the spec. The end result is this:
`\A(?i:urn:(?!urn:)(?<nid>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,31}[^-]):(?<nss>(?:[-a-z0-9()+,.:=@;$_!*'&~\/]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)(?:\?\+(?<rcomponent>.*?))?(?:\?=(?<qcomponent>.*?))?(?:#(?<fcomponent>.*?))?)\z`

Comment: You're welcome, just beware that this version will match and capture those three components only if they are in this exact order. I haven't read enough of the spec to know if they can appear in a different order

Comment: If anybody comes looking for a Javascript compatible RegExp, I used this as a starting point (Regex101 doesn't convert automatically) and Regex101 to come up with this: `/^urn:([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,31}):((?:[-a-z0-9()+,.:=@;$_!*'&~\/]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)(?:(\?\+)((?:(?!\?=).)*))(?:(\?=)((?:(?!#).)*))?(?:(#)(.*))?$/i` (which you can find at https://regex101.com/r/vc7kos/1).  Technically, the components can't have any (`.`) characters in them.  But elaborating what is legal would be a real pain.

Comment: If you want something even stricter (for Javascript), you can find it here: https://regex101.com/r/xyZhoK/1.  This restricts the characters in components as well.  I won't even post the Regexp here, it is too long. ;-)

Comment: I just realized the r-component wasn't optional in that last one.  Here is an updated one: https://regex101.com/r/WMty99/1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate string with Uniform Resource Names (URNs) 8141: [rfc8141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141)  You can refer to [URN8141Test.java](https://github.com/BruceZu/broken_colored_glass/blob/master/project/src/test/java/URN8141Test.java) and [URN8141.java](https://github.com/BruceZu/broken_colored_glass/blob/master/project/src/main/java/URN8141.java)

It has been used in our team for a few years.