# How to use regex capture groups in postgres stored procedures (if possible at all)?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, regex-group

In a system, I'm using a standard urn ([RFC8141](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8141#section-2.3.1)) as one of the fields. From that urn, one can derive a unique identifier. The weird thing about the urns described in RFC8141 is that you can have two different urns which are equal.

In order to check for unique keys, I need to extract different parts of the urn that make a unique key. To do so, I have [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/SxOh4R/1) ([Regex which matches URN by rfc8141](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59032211/regex-which-matches-urn-by-rfc8141)):

```
\A(?i:urn:(?!urn:)(?<nid>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,31}[^-]):(?<nss>(?:[-a-z0-9()+,.:=@;$_!*'&~\/]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)(?:\?\+(?<rcomponent>.*?))?(?:\?=(?<qcomponent>.*?))?(?:#(?<fcomponent>.*?))?)\z
```

which results in a five named capture groups (`nid`, `nss`, `rcomponent`, `qcomponent` en `fcomponent`). Only the `nid` and `nss` are important to check for uniqueness/equality. Or: even if the components change, as long as `nid` and `nss` are the same, two items/records are equal (no matter the values of the components). `nid` is checked case-insensitive, `nss` is checked case-sensitive.

Now, in order to check for uniqueness/equality, I'm defining a 'cleaned urn', which is the primary key. I've added a trigger, so I can extract the different capture groups. What I'd like to do is:

1. extract the `nid` and `nss` (see regex) of the `urn`
2. capture them by name. *This is where I don't know how to do it: how can I capture these two capture groups in a postgresql stored procedure?*
3. add them as 'cleaned urn', lowercasing `nid` (so to have case-insensitivity on that part) and url-encoding or url-decoding the string (one of the two, it doesn't matter, as long as it's consistent). (I'm also not sure if there's is a url encode/decode function in Postgres, but I that'll be another question once the previous one is solved :) ).

Example:

- all these `urn`s are equal/equivalent (and I want the primary key to be `urn:example:a123,z456`):

  - `urn:example:a123,z456`
  - `URN:example:a123,z456`
  - `urn:EXAMPLE:a123,z456`
  - `urn:example:a123,z456?+abc` (`?+` denotes the start of the rcomponent)
  - `urn:example:a123,z456?=xyz/something` (`?=` denotes the start of the qcomponent)
  - `urn:example:a123,z456#789`  (`#` denotes the start of the fcomponent)
  - `urn:example:a123%2Cz456`
  - `URN:EXAMPLE:a123%2cz456`
- `urn:example:A123,z456` and `urn:Example:A123,z456` both have key `urn:example:A123,z456`, which is different from the previous examples (because of the case-sensitiveness of the `A123,z456`).
- just for completeness: `urn:example:a123,z456?=xyz/something` is different from `urn:example:a123,z456/something?=xyz`: everything after `?=` (or `?+` or `#`) can be omitted, so the `/something` is part of the primary key in the latter case, but not in the former. (That's what the regex is actually capturing already.)

**== EDIT 1: unnamed capture groups ==**

with unnamed capture groups, this would be doing the same:

```
select 
  g[2] as nid, 
  g[3] as nss, 
  g[4] as rcomp, 
  g[5] as qcomp, 
  g[6] as fcomp 
from (
  select regexp_matches('uRn:example:a123,z456?=xyz/something', 
                        '\A(urn:(?!urn:)([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,31}[^-]):((?:[-a-z0-9()+,.:=@;$_!*''&~\/]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)(?:\?\+(.*?))?(?:\?=(.*?))?(?:#(.*?))?)$', 'i')
    g) 
  as ar;
```

(`g[1]` is the full match, which I don't need)

I updated the query:

- case insensitive matching should be done as flag
- no capturing groups (postgres seems to have issues with names capturing groups)

and did a select on the array, splitting the array into columns.

Comment: Do you have the option of using PL/python?

Comment: Unfortunately, no...

Answer (score 0):

Named capture don't seem to be supported and there seem to be some issues with the greedy/lazy lookup and negative lookahead. So, here's a solution that works fine:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    if not exists (SELECT 1 FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'urn') then
        CREATE TYPE urn AS (nid text, nss text, rcomp text, qcomp text, fcomp text);
    end if;
END
$$;

CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION spliturn(urnstring text) 
    RETURNS urn as $$
    DECLARE
      urn urn;
      urnregex text = concat(
        '\A(urn:(?!urn:)',
        '([a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{1,31}[^-]):',
        '((?:[-a-z0-9()+,.:=@;$_!*''&~\/]|%[0-9a-f]{2})+)',
        '(?:\?\+(.*?))??',
        '(?:\?=(.*?))??',
        '(?:#(.*?))??',
        ')$');
    BEGIN
      select 
        lower(g[2]) as nid, 
        g[3] as nss, 
        g[4] as rcomp, 
        g[5] as qcomp, 
        g[6] as fcomp
      into urn
      from (select regexp_matches(urnstring, urnregex, 'i')
      g) as ar;
    RETURN urn;
    END;
$$ language 'plpgsql' immutable strict;
```

note

- no named groups (`?<...>`)
- indicate case insensitive search with a flag
- replacement of `\z` with `$` to match the end of the string
- escaping a quote with another quote (`''`) to allow for quotes
- the double `??` for [non-greedy search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9/functions-matching.html) (Table 9-14)